# JS: how to merge arrays with objects without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
let arrayFirst = [{name: 'a', num: 1}, { name: 'b', num: 1} ]
let arraySecond = [{name: 'a', num: 1}, { name: 'b', num: 1} ]
let arrayThid = [{name: 'a', num: 1}, { name: 'c', num: 1} ]
```

...
...
...

expected output:

```
[{name: 'a', num: 3}, { name: 'b', num: 2}, { name: 'c', num: 1} ]
```

I only found array inner object sum up, but how about arrays sum up by its object key-value?

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: Are you limited to only 3 arrays or it could be more?

Comment: @TiisetsoTjabane
Actually, it is 4 arrays above(would add more later) with 23 keys(would add more later), but I just need some kind expert to guide me the way, then I would try for-loop myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below function to group and sum the values. The method takes as many arrays (or objects) as you want and sums them based on groupby (name in your case) and sumkey

```js
function sumArrays(groupby, sumkey, ...arrays) {
  return [...arrays.flat().reduce((a, b) => a.set(b[groupby], (a.get(b[groupby]) || 0) + b[sumkey]), new Map())].map(([k, v]) => ({
    [groupby]: k,
    [sumkey]: v
  }))
}

console.log(sumArrays('name', 'num', arrayFirst, arraySecond, arrayThid));
```

```html
<script>
arrayFirst = [{
  name: 'a',
  num: 1
}, {
  name: 'b',
  num: 1
}]
let arraySecond = [{
  name: 'a',
  num: 1
}, {
  name: 'b',
  num: 1
}]
let arrayThid = [{
  name: 'a',
  num: 1
}, {
  name: 'c',
  num: 1
}]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayFirst = [{ name: 'a', num: 1 }, { name: 'b', num: 1 }]
let arraySecond = [{ name: 'a', num: 1 }, { name: 'b', num: 1 }]
let arrayThid = [{ name: 'a', num: 1 }, { name: 'c', num: 1 }]

// [{name: 'a', num: 3}, { name: 'b', num: 2}, { name: 'c', num: 1} ]
var r = {}

addObject = (arrayObj) => {
    arrayObj.forEach(first => {
        if (r[first.name] == null) r[first.name] = 0;
        r[first.name] += first.num
    })
}

addObject(arrayFirst)
addObject(arraySecond)
addObject(arrayThid)

console.log(r)
var result = []

Object.keys(r).forEach(key => {
    result.push({ name: key, num: r[key] })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the help of `Array.concat` and `findIndex`:

```js
let arrayFirst = [{
    name: 'a',
    num: 1
}, {
    name: 'b',
    num: 1
}]
let arraySecond = [{
    name: 'a',
    num: 1
}, {
    name: 'b',
    num: 1
}]
let arrayThid = [{
    name: 'a',
    num: 1
}, {
    name: 'c',
    num: 1
}]

var result = [];

arrayThid.concat((arrayFirst.concat(arraySecond))).forEach(function(obj) {
    let index = result.findIndex(x => x.name === obj.name);
    if (index == -1) {
        result.push(obj);
    } else {
        result[index].num += obj.num;
    }
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method:

```
const result = arrayFirst.concat(arraySecond).concat(arrayThid).reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.name] = a[c.name] || {name: c.name, num: 0};
  a[c.name].num += c.num;
  return a;
}, {});
```

An example:

```js
let arrayFirst = [{name: 'a', num: 1}, { name: 'b', num: 1} ]
let arraySecond = [{name: 'a', num: 1}, { name: 'b', num: 1} ]
let arrayThid = [{name: 'a', num: 1}, { name: 'c', num: 1} ]

const result = arrayFirst.concat(arraySecond).concat(arrayThid).reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.name] = a[c.name] || {name: c.name, num: 0};
  a[c.name].num += c.num;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion @baao answer is great and generic. However if you want something simpler try:

```
[arrayFirst, arraySecond, arrayThird].flat().filter((item, index, array) => array.findIndex(i => (i.name === item.name)) === index)
```

or if you want check whole objects in arrays you could use

```
[arrayFirst, arraySecond, arrayThird].flat().filter((item, index, array) => array.findIndex(i => (JSON.stringify(i) === JSON.stringify(item))) === index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can cache the results in object:

```
const addSumToCachedNum = (acc, item) => {
    const { name, num } = item;
    const current = acc[name] || {};
    const currentNum = current.num || 0;

    acc[name] = {
      name,
      num: currentNum + num,
    };

    return acc;
}

const sumArrayByKey = (...items) => {
    const mergedArray = [].concat(...items);
    const sumObject = mergedArray.reduce(addSumToCachedNum, {});

    return Object.values(sumObject);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` for grouping the values and the function `Object.values` for extracting the grouped values as an array.

```js
let arrayFirst = [{name: 'a', num: 1}, { name: 'b', num: 1} ];
let arraySecond = [{name: 'a', num: 1}, { name: 'b', num: 1} ];
let arrayThid = [{name: 'a', num: 1}, { name: 'c', num: 1} ];

let result = Object.values(arrayFirst.concat(arraySecond).concat(arrayThid).reduce((a, {name, num}) => {
  (a[name] || (a[name] = {name, num: 0})).num += num;
  return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```